# Increased font size in "about me" box

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

Recently, the font in "about me" box in user profile grew from 13 px to 15 px (here on Meta, and elsewhere on sites with updated CSS). Compare: [old](https://web.archive.org/web/20150721151927/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) vs [new](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=profile), or see the screenshots below.

Is this intentional, or a CSS bug?

It may be just an effect of the change, but it seems odd that the base font  size in one part of the profile is 15px while everywhere else on the same page it's 13px.

## Old

> [image: old]

## New

> [image: new]

Comment: No wonder something looked off today

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, can't see a reason to make is **that** big

Comment: Retagged as (bug) since it looks like one.